# How to manage the deletion and recreation of a main frame and a working thread in a multithreaded application in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

## Introduction

I am new to multithreading. I have an created a GUI application in c++ on windows 10 using wxWidgets. A worker thread communicates in the background via sockets and appends events to some event handlers from the main thread (GUI); I have **two** available protocols for the communication, and I allow the user to choose among those at the beginning (before instantiating the thread). To append events, I have a few shared pointers on the event handlers; a bit like in [this tutorial](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication#Sending_events_to_the_main_thread), where it keeps a pointer of the m_parent. To communicate with the working thread, I created a queue using a mutex and semaphore, also like in the [tutorial](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication#Bidirectional_Communication). For now, everything works.

---

Now, I want to let the user change the protocol while the application runs. I have thus a menu with a related button. This button calls the following function (create_app()) that deletes the top window and the communication thread and recreates everything. That is where I have problems.

```
bool cApp::create_app() {
    wxWindow* main_window = GetTopWindow();
    
    // If there is already a window, delete everything before creation
    if(main_window) {
        //thread_communication->Wait(); // Should I wait for the thread to finish? I shouldn't
        if (thread_communication->Delete() != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR) { // Should I delete it since it should be destroyed when Entry is finished
            std::cerr << "DELETE IMPOSSIBLE!" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        if (main_window->Destroy() != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR) { // Here I can't delete the window
            std::cerr << "DELETE WINDOW IMPOSSIBLE!" << std::endl; // prints
            return false;
        }
        
        SetTopWindow(NULL);
    }
    
    // Create everything
    m_frame1 = new MainFrame(*this);
    SetTopWindow(m_frame1);
    m_frame1->Show();

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<wxEvtHandler>> evt_handlers;
    m_frame1->get_handlers(evt_handlers);
    
    // Construct the working thread with the evt handlers and the queue from the main window
    thread_communication = std::unique_ptr<ThreadCom>(new ThreadCom(evt_handlers, m_frame1->get_queue());
    wxThreadError err = thread_communication->Create();

    ...
    
    err = thread_communication->Run();
    
    ...

    return true;
}


bool cApp::OnInit() {
    return create_app();
}
```

When the user click the related button, it calls this create_app function but before sends a task via the queue to the working thread with the highest priority (meaning it will be the next task achieved by it); afterwards, in the working thread, it exits after poping the task the while loop in Entry. Thus, the working thread should terminate there.

---

## Problem

I have problem when deleting the thread and the application. I have memory leaks since, I guess, they share common material (pointers).

When I try to use Wait, I have first a assert !IsDetached. That is because I cannot wait for a detached thread. If I continue, the programm crashes (Access violation reading location) during the thread->Delete() call.

If I don't use Wait, the thread->Delete() call works fine. Afterwards, the program crashes at main_window->Destroy(); the return code is not ok thus it prints "DELETE WINDOW IMPOSSIBLE" with an Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation message.

So, how should I proceed? Should I implement destructors in the classes? How can I delete the thread and the app safely?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: GUI's and threading is often not a good combination. Generally the event loop of the windows and widgets needs to be in the same thread that created them. The common way to handle these things is to do all GUI handling in a single thread, then use worker threads for specific non-GUI processing. For communication between the GUI thread and worker threads use some notifications, shared variables, and other communication data structures.

Comment: I did as explained in the tutorial using the event mechanism. In there, the thread is not instantiated in the main frame but in the wxApp. And it works fine. However, I don't know how to manually delete stuff since they have shared objects. But, for example, I may share objects via shared pointers. And thus, I should not be concerned about deleting them right.

Comment: @Chenoille, look at the `thread` sample and `wxThread` documentation. Also - I don't think you need to recreate anything. You should stop one thread and start the other.

Comment: @Igor Thank's. And I did it but I saw on a post that I couldn't init twice a wxLocale (because I use it somewhere) and thus, to bypass this, one could delete the Frame and recreate it. That is why I wanted to do that.

Comment: @Chenoille, no you shouldn't. But it shouldn't require you to recreate a frame neither.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want to check whether an instance of your app running there is single instance checker https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/classwx_single_instance_checker.html